# How to test two methods for their capability of quantifiy target?

Tags: t-test, model-comparison

I have two quantitative methods A and B, and I ran a series of measurements against a known quantity of target. 
The difference from the expectation was 56 and 13. To check which method is truly better at quantifying, I ran a t-test using R providing the expected value as average of the distribution. I got:

```
> t.test(A$val, mu=405)

    One Sample t-test

data:  A$val
t = -5.0987, df = 119, p-value = 1.305e-06
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 405
95 percent confidence interval:
 331.7295 372.7205
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  352.225 

> t.test(B$val, mu=405)

    One Sample t-test

data:  B$val
t = -0.87175, df = 119, p-value = 0.3851
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 405
95 percent confidence interval:
 371.7133 417.9367
sample estimates:
mean of x 
  394.825
```

Can I say that method A was significantly different from the expected value but not B hence method B is a better quantitative method than A?

Is the format of the test correct for this context? Should it be two-way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct syntax for doing two-sided t tests om R. It seems to me
that two-sided tests are appropriate because you would not want to use
a method that consistently gives values either above or below target.

You might want to pay specific attention to the two confidence
intervals for the 'true' mean of each method:

- The 95% confidence interval for Method A is  $(331.7295, 372.7205),$
  which does not include target value $405.$
- The 95% confidence interval for Method B is  $(371.7133, 417.9367),$
  which *does* include $405.$